# How to uninstall revolutionary rooting tool from Android devices

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, root-access

i have different android devices and all are rooted with the help of revolutionary tool, now i want to remove revolutionary tool from my device is there anyway so that remove all those tool which are installed on my devices ?

Comment: What exact devices are these?  The procedure for removing the s-off varies.

Comment: i want to remove it from htc desire

Answer (score 0):

To re-S-ON an HTC Desire, you will need the following

1. USB cable
2. Fastboot drivers installed, available [here](http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/revolutionary).
3. Android flasher and appropriate HBOOT images available [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1387484).
4. Optionally, an appropriate stock RUU, available [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695667).  Either select the one for your carrier or use the RUU_Bravo_HTC_WWE_1.21.405.2_Radio_32.36.00.28U_4. 06.00.02_2_release_126984_signed.exe one.

Ok, now that you have your tools, now for the actual doing.

1. Extract all the files in the revert to stock zip.
2. Turn on USB debugging and plug in phone.
3. Either use the "click this.bat" file or run `fastboot flash hboot engHBOOToverARX.img` from a command prompt in the folder where you extracted the the revert to stock files.
4. Shutdown phone and power it back up holding the volume down button, then select fastboot.  It should show you as S-OFF and using HBOOT 6.98.2000
5. Fire up android flasher and select to flash the hboot.img file
6. Restart phone again.  You should now be S-ON.
7. Optionally, run the RUU downloaded above.  This will put your phone back in completely stock condition, perfect for warranty claims, etc.